# How to create a switch Node that recognizes if a texture is connected to the node input?

Tags: node-editor

I'm trying to create a little trick, which recognizes if a texture type node has a texture inside it, so if yes, like in this example, it should set the MixRGB value to 1, I'm using a math node set to "Greater Than ", but obviously, this interacts on the parts where the pixels have a value higher than" 0 "but on the others it doesn't interact and the color stays on red. Tracing the Blender logo I'm using as a test.

Is there a way to "Smooth" those values, and make everything set to RGB "Green" if a map is inserted into the node and has at least one pixel with a value greater than 0?

**In short**:

I would like solid color Red if no texture is inserted in the node, and all green if a texture inserted in the node

[image]

**Edit:**
Something was suggested to me in a previous answer. But the problem is that in Blender, an empty Texture Node fires RGB values: (0,0,0) in Eevee, and (1,0,1) in Cycles. So, use solution would be with regard to RGB values only (Leaving aside the Alpha factor for now)
Feedback like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi. You should indicate if it is for Eevee, Cycles or both.

Comment: Hi @lemon , I would like it to work on all 2 and also understand how math can be used here. if possible.

Comment: Python As stated in the bottom Awnser

Answer (score 5):

Here are three ways to do it:

1. Python Nodes API: with Python nodes like mentioned before, you can create a smart/dynamic node, that can change values depending on Python properties, like if an image is inserted or not
2. if you don't want to use PyNodes, you can use drivers, here's a simple driver that does what you need (change "Image Texture" in drivers panel to the name of your Image Texture Node):
3. if you plan to have such functionality inside a node group, you could set a chosen default value for a socket (a negative value would work in this case), then if nothing is connected to the socket, it would have the default value, which you compare and detect, if something is then connected to the socket, that would change its value, now the compare would return 0, it all works out, because Image Texture Node won't produce a negative value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a nice solution. Obviously the name in the driver needs to match that of the Image Texture node it's relating to (the name, not the label). What's the third way..?

Comment: Oh, the third way was relevant to node groups, will edit the answer to include.

Comment: Your solution is very beautiful and useful! Actually, it hadn't even crossed my mind. In any case, I have had bad experiences with drivers, especially if you switch to other computers. I would like a mathematical solution with nodes without the use of "Script". It's not really easy to get a node that does this. Someone suggests that this is probably not possible. But I keep hoping . I don't understand what you mean in solution 3. If I showed an example it would be nice

Comment: @NoobCat indeed drivers do have their issues, sure will edit answer to explain method three more, the third solution is more mathematical.

Comment: note that the third solution is for node groups, example to check if something is connected to the socket or not, as for if an image is set or not, drivers and scripting should be the way to go

Comment: @IyadAhmed Carefull when you say that "Image Texture Node won't produce a negative value"... Some image formats (hdr and exr) do work with negative values, and the node will still output those.

Comment: Oh, indeed I didn't think of that, I guess we just use a very large value instead, even if it technically could produce a very large value it would work I believe for most cases.

Comment: The real problem, seems to be the Empty texture node, In Eevee it produces 0,0,0 in Cycles 1,0,1. I have updated the question. It seems like a very arduous undertaking. So the comparison is really difficult to make.

Comment: but also if the image contains black or magenta it would be marked too, so I believe drivers is the best way

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to 'sample all values in the image to determine whether something is present' in this way. The Image Texture node takes a vector and returns the value in the image at that specific point. As such it can only return a single point at a time. Having no image returns a fixed value for all pixels but this is still within the range of what a 'valid' image could feasibly return so there is no way of determining whether it's an image or a default 'no image'.

Therefore, I don't think it is possible to achieve what is being asked.

Comment: With a python node, it would be possible to traverse any input nodes, and check if any of them is an Image Texture, and if it has some texture assigned.

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility. But that's not for me (Unfortunately)

Comment: @Rich Sedman , Technically it is feasible, practically a disaster. I explain. I assume that a complete "Black" image, I do not think it is used for any purpose. So By updating my question, maybe you will understand what I mean. The problem is precisely that Blender Eevee Blank image is 0,0,0 while Cycles is Magenta, 1,0,1. With the distance node you can evaluate if there is something or not, but the problem is that you cannot evaluate which rendering engine you are in. Apart with the use of drivers